# How to make discord.py bot read and reply to messages with specific keywords

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord.py bot and I want it to scan messages that are sent on the server and reply to the ones that have the specific keyword I want.

I tried this:

```
@gameBot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if "Hello" in message.content.lower:
        await ctx.send("Hi")
    else:
        pass
```

But the when I use the other commands it simply passes them and it also has a few errors.

Answer (score 1):

on_message takes `self` and `message`. `self` is used if you are using a cog and `message` is what is sent.

```py
@gameBot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "hello" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Hi")
    await gameBot.process_commands(message)
```

Lower is a function so you must use `()` at the end of it.

Comment: Your `"Hello"` is still uppercase, which would result in this condition to always skip to the falsy case ;)

Comment: There you go @PascalStockert